# reset_mock(return_value=True) with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, mocking

I'm using Python 2.7 and have installed mock 2.0.0.

Is there any way to get the functionality of `reset_mock(return_value=True)` that is described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)?

Comment: What's the error you get? 'TypeError: reset_mock() got an unexpected keyword argument'

Comment: @Daniel, yes, that's right.

Comment: @JeffO'Neill: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @nakiya, nope.  Had to refactor my tests so I didn't need it.